# HTML format of smtp in ruby to send mail

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, smtp

I wrote a ruby script to send mails using smtp by reading the contents of a file. The contents of a file are:

```
+3456|0|2013-04-16|2013-04-19
+3456|0|2013-04-16|2013-05-19
```

And my code to send the mail is as below:

```
content = File.read(file_name)   
message = << MESSAGE_END   
From: from@localdomain.com
To: to@localdomain.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP e-mail test
Body
**HTML CODE to display the table with rows equal to the number of records in the file**
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp| 
  smtp.send_message message, 'from@localdomain.com','to@localdomain.com'
end
```

Now my problem is how to write an html code to create a table with rows and columns equal to the number of records inside the file(as the records in the file varies accordingly)? The records in the file are always '|' separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) helper and [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split). For example:

```
def row_markup(row)
  content_tag(:tr) do
    row.map{ |elem| content_tag(:td, elem) }.reduce(:+)
  end
end

def table_markup(rows)
  content_tag(:table) do
    rows.map{ |row| row_markup(row.split("|")) }.reduce(:+)
  end
end
```

then call

```
table_markup(read_data_from_file.split("\n"))
```

Comment: I overlooked the ruby-on-rails tag, so your solution is definitely nicer because it uses built-in helpers. +1

Comment: I would suggest using `join` instead of `reduce(&:+)`, though.

Comment: normally i'd agree, but i've run into issues with `join` where you then have to make it html_safe. reducing always works

Comment: Thanks a lot AJcodez. Its working fine. Ruby is indeed very interesting to work on.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your input file is located at `./input.txt`, then you could do something like this:

```
require 'builder'

html = Builder::XmlMarkup.new
html.table do
  File.open('./input.txt', 'r').each_line do |line|
   html.tr do
      line.chomp.split('|').each do |column|
        html.td column
      end
    end
  end
end

message << html.to_html
```